# android.location.Geocoder

Tags: android, google-geocoder

Is there any license limits on this api call? (e.g frequency)

Any pointers? ([geocoding](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) seems to be the base for this api wrapper and does contain limitations)